I need help identifying the purpose and type of a block in simulink of a DC motor modelling

I need to understand the purpose and type of the block encircled in blue from this simulink simulation from which i only have images, not the actual file.

This? or This Can't confirm since I don't have access to simulink at the moment.

From Matlab website
Solver Configuration Block (Emphasis mine)

Each physical network represented by a connected Simscape™ block diagram requires solver settings information for simulation. The Solver Configuration block specifies the solver parameters that your model needs before you can begin simulation.
Each topologically distinct Simscape block diagram requires exactly one Solver Configuration block to be connected to it.

From another source

Iterations are also often necessary for each Simscape physical network for both explicit and implicit solvers. The iterations in Simscape are limited by setting the checkbox, “Use fixed-cost runtime consistency iterations” and entering the number of nonlinear iterations in the Solver Configuration block (see Figure 9). If the local solver option is used, it is recommended to initially set the number of nonlinear iterations to 2 or 3.

I don't have experience with simscape.
